# Android font out of view on small screen

Tags: android, textview, font-size, screen-size

I have several text views that take up the majority of the screen in landscape view in a relativelayout and the font size i have set is quite big (150dp). The text views are all timers and the furthest to the right is the "seconds" textview.

My problem is that when testing on a phone with a small screen res the seconds are way outside the limit of the screen and can't be seen. They are in perfect place on normal to large screen resolutions just not on a small screen.

Is there any way i can force the "seconds" text view to stay on screen, without adjusting the font size or margins between each text view? Even if it means looking cramped on a small screen i can live with that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

This is the corresponding code for the relative layout and linear layout containing the hour and minute text views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:keepScreenOn="true" android:background="@drawable/background2">


<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout08"

android:paddingLeft="20dip" android:paddingRight="30dip"
android:background="@drawable/trans_img" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:paddingBottom="20dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true">

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewHr1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dip" android:gravity="right" 
android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="150dp" 
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewHr2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
android:gravity="right" android:textColor="@color/white" 
android:textSize="150dp"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewSeperate" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dip" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/colon" android:layout_height="55dip"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewMin1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
android:gravity="right" android:textColor="@color/white" 
android:textSize="150dp"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewMin2" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="150dp" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"></TextView
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for the 2nd linear layout, within this relative layout 8:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewSeconds" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="20" 
android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:textColor="@color/white" 
android:textSize="55dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting layout_weight settings.

To do it try following:
set in parent **weight_sum = "1.0"**

And in child percentage value, how much space they need to take i.e. **layout_weight="0.8"** and **layout_weight="0.2"**, remember to set **layout_width = "0dp"** in all elements in parent.

Comment: Thanks

Would that mean setting the weight_sum = 1.0 for the relative layout which contains all the textviews and then weight = 0.2 for the "seconds" textview which is being cut off?

Also if i set the relative layout width to 0dp would that not mess it up? As there is a backgroung for it

Thanks again

Comment: It won't be messed up. If we use layout_weight view is drawn to fit percentage value of the screen, so in 0.8 it's 80% of place on the screen. This is how you should handle the problem of different screen sizes.

Comment: I tried this approach, but for some reason cannot get it to work.

So i have a relative layout which then contains two Linear layouts. The first linear layout contains the hour and min text view the second contains the seconds text view.

i applied android:weightSum="1.0" to the relative layout then for linear layout 1(containing hours and mins) i set android:layout_weight="0.8" and for linear layout 2(seconds) i applied android:layout_weight="0.2".

I set layout_width="0dp" for both linear layouts.

I Appreciate any clarification

Thanks

Comment: past code of this element, I will test it. Now I cannot see where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, i've edited my above post with the code. I haven't added the weight elements above so you can see the code without them. Thanks again